# Unable to locate/no such element python selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am trying to click the place order button.  Button code :

```
<button type="button" data-ng-disabled="activeStep.position !== 6" class="primary-button place-order-btn" data-ng-click="VerifyOrderInformation()">
            Place Order
        </button>
```

I have tried two methods and both cannot locate the element.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"mainContent\"]/aside/div[2]/button").click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("primary-button place-order-btn").click()
```

I have a 5 second sleep preceding this string to allow for the page to load and I don't see any frames/iframes

Thanks in advance to any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**Did you try:**

```
//button[@data-ng-click="VerifyOrderInformation()"]
```

**you can use any attribute as:**

```
//tagname[@attribute="attribute-value"]
```

**you can have multiple condition as:**

```
//tagname[@attribute="attribute-value" and @attribute2="attribute2-value"]
```

**so:**

```
//button[@data-ng-click="VerifyOrderInformation()" and @class="primary-button place-order-btn"]
```